# Writing a service with an external dependancy

Tags: ember.js

I am writing a service to wrap a couple of Google Places API calls that I need for my app.

Something like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  googleAutocompleteService: null,
  placePredictions(query) {
    var self = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      ...
      self.get('googleAutocompleteService').getPlacePredictions(request, callback);
    });
  },
  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('googleAutocompleteService',
             new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService());
  },
});
```

Now I obviously need to have the Google Maps API loaded. For the moment I have included it in my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    {{content-for 'body'}}

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&libraries=places" async defer></script>

    ...

    {{content-for 'body-footer'}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Occasionally my service will load before the maps API is initialized causing an error. I can simply remove `async defer` from the tag and load it synchronously, but there must be a way to have my service load the external library as a dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the google service as computed promise property. This is a clean way to assure it will be lazy-loaded and only once.

`npm i ember-inject-script --save-dev`

```js
import Ember from 'ember';
import injectScript from 'ember-inject-script';

const {
  getOwner,
  computed,
  PromiseProxyMixin
  Service
} = Ember;

const ObjectPromiseProxy = ObjectProxy.extend(PromiseProxyMixin);
const GOOGLE_PLACES_SCRIPT_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&libraries=places';

export default Service.extend({
  googleAutocompleteService: computed(function() {
    return ObjectPromiseProxy.create(getOwner(this).ownerInjection(), {
      promise: injectScript(GOOGLE_PLACES_SCRIPT_URL).then(() => {
        return new window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
      })
    });
  }),
  placePredictions(query) {
    return this.get('googleAutocompleteService').then((resolvedService) => {
      //...
      resolvedService.getPlacePredictions( /* ... */ );
      //...
      return {}; // return whatever you want the promise to resolve;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This looks great. Am I correct in saying that `ObjectPromiseProxy` is an Ember object that is essentially created from the returned data of the included promise?

Comment: Yes, but you can't access the data, without resolving it first. It is also very useful for templates with async properties. `{{someObject.someProperty}}` will be rendered seamlessly, when `someObject` is created with the `PromiseProxyMixin`.

Answer (score 1):

One way that I've handled this is either in a component or a routes lifecycle hooks.

If you're using the maps on a particular route, you could do add a `getScript` in the `beforeModel`/`afterModel` hooks:

```
beforeModel() {
   return Ember.$.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&libraries=places');
}
```

Now, I'm not entirely sure if that will solve the problem in the services.

If all of your mapping work is contained in a component, you could try the same thing with a `didInitAttrs()` hook.

It may also be worth a try in the services `init()`  hook, though I'm not sure how if there is a way to have init wait for the promise to fulfil.